# XtraGrid with unique values filter

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, datatable, xtragrid

I am using XtraGrid in my application. Now, I want to display only Unique values for particular column when user will click filter button. I want to display this list check box items initially all checked. Also I want the information that what items user has selected/deselected from from checked list box.

Any idea?

Comment: how about posting some code. What have you tried and what is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to implement a custom filter dialog, as described here:

http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument698